# Please explain the ... operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

the following tutorial (https://dojo.io/tutorials/1010_containers_and_injecting_state/) contains the code snippet:

[image]

which I don't understand and never saw before. It looks a little bit the "rest parameters" from TypeScript. What exactly does the "..." mean? Is there somewhere a documentation? I could not find anything.

Comment: Generally don't post pictures post code.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [spread operator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html). It essentially unwraps an object / array you are spreading and puts all of the properties where the spread operator is. A very simple example for objects:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' };
const b = { ...a };
```

This "spreads" the properties of `a` inside of the object literal. So think of it as doing two steps: take all properties:

```
{ { foo: 'bar' } }
```

...and remove the object wrapper:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

The result is that `a` is equivalent to `b`.

You can use this to copy properties into objects and set defaults

```
const a = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const b = { a: 2, c: 3 };
const c = { a: 0, z: 4, ...a, ...b };
```

`c` will be `{ a: 2, z: 4, b: 2, c: 3 }`. We can do this in two steps again:

```
{ a: 0, z: 4, { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, c: 3 } }
```

Now unwrap the inner objects:

```
{ a: 0, z: 4, a: 1, b: 2, a: 2, c: 3 }
```

The last time a property was declared takes precedence, so remove `a: 0` and `a: 1`.

You can do this with arrays too and it works the same:

```
const a = [2, 3];
const b = [1, ...a];
```

This will be `[1, 2, 3]`. Doing the steps:

```
[1, [2, 3] ]
```

Then unwrap the inner array to get `[1, 2, 3]`.

Note that when you unwrap you need to unwrap into something, so doing:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = ...a
```

This isn't allowed because we can't have `b = 1, 2, 3` -- that's just not valid syntax. However, it does work for function arguments with arrays.